# Does the MongoDB connection string need the authentication details for each server in ReplicaSet?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

We've discovered that our secondary is not authenticating properly after having the primary fail over to it. We have 2 MongoDB servers (v3.4) both properly setup in a replicaset:

```
mongo1:27017
mongo2:27017
```

And our connection string (for Node.js's MongoDB driver v2.2.19), is like this:

`mongodb://username:password@mongo1,mongo2/db?replicaSet=rs0`

Now, our primary failed and the secondary, `mongo2` was elected primary. However, DB calls failed with 'not authorized' errors. So I took another look at the MongoDB docs:

`mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

It looks ambiguous, could the `username:password` be needed for each host? But that's weird because they are all replicated so the users should be the same, right?

I even tried it, using this connection string in the application:

`mongodb://username:password@mongo1,username:password@mongo2/db?replicaSet=rs0`

But that fails with: `Error: Username with password containing an unescaped colon`

The username and passwords are alphanumeric, so there seems to be a parsing problem with that style URI. But with the original, it's not authenticated properly. So these problems seem at odds with each other. I have verified in standalone mode that the user exists on both servers, and has the proper permissions. So I'm not sure where the problem lies. I found another [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702142/mongodb-replicaset-authentication-issue-with-secondary) with a different driver, but no answers :(

Comment: No, the format of `mongodb://username:password@mongo1,mongo2/db?replicaSet=rs0` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could never figure this out but updating the Node.js driver (v2.2.19 -> v2.2.33) seems to have fixed it. I didn't see anything relevant in the changelog and I'm not interested enough to compare diffs. C'est la vie de programming.